# Change formula as per data in last, second last and 7th last column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which has 3196 records and records are added daily.

The formulas are:

1. `=SUMIF('Raw Data'!$I:$I,Sheet2!AA18,'Raw Data'!$CQ:$CQ)`  ----since CQ is the last column today and tomorrow it will be CR
2. `=SUMIF('Raw Data'!$I:$I,Sheet2!AA18,'Raw Data'!$CP:$CP)`   -----since CP is the second last column today and tomorrow it will be CQ
3. `=SUMIF('Raw Data'!$I:$I,Sheet2!AA18,'Raw Data'!$CJ:$CJ)`   ------since CJ is the eight last column and tomorrow it will be CK

I want when I update the RAW DATA sheet, these records also get updated.

Comment: Do you have any headers for the columns?

Answer (score 0):

I like to suggest the formula below (002).

`=SUMIF('Raw Data'!$I:$I,Sheet2!AA18,INDEX('Raw Data'!$A:$ZZ,0,COUNTA('Raw Data'!$2:$2)))`

Instead of specifying the last column by name (such as "CQ") it specifies the last column by its position. My formula determines that position in row 2. Modify to suit.

Of course, if `COUNTA('Raw Data'!$2:$2)` is the last column than `COUNTA('Raw Data'!$2:$2)-1` must be panultimate one, and `COUNTA('Raw Data'!$2:$2)-7` would be the one pertaining to the same day last week. You can use this kind of adjustment also if you don't have a row that has something in every column (like $2:$2 above).

Note that the method will work until the last column is ZZ. After that you will need to expand the column range `'Raw Data'!$A:$ZZ`.